# Preventing Path Traversal Best Practise?

Tags: web-application, php

Script:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$var = $_GET['var'];
$var = str_replace(array('/', '../'), array('', ''), $var);

echo file_get_contents($var);
```

Is it possible to exploit Path Traversal without using forward slash?

In other words, would this code be enough to prevent Path Traversal?

```
$var = str_replace(array('/', '../'), array('', ''), $var);
```

- If Yes:

  1. What about backward slash? is it safe?
  2. Would double encoding and hex encoding have any affect on that?
- If No:

  1. How would you rate it impact?
  2. What is your suggestion for a better solution?

> PS: Operation System: Linux

Comment: Do you mean directory traversals in general or LFI in particular? Also, it matters how the path in `$var` is handled. Is it just fed into `fopen()` - or maybe even `system()`? That's important to know since paths might be expanded (e.g. `~`), or you might be on a system where paths work differently (e.g. backslashes on Windows).

Comment: @Arminius I have updated my question, check above

Comment: Well, it's definitely an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @Arminius No, it's not, this is LFI vulnerability.

Comment: Your example 100% creates an XSS flaw.

Comment: @Arminius It's LFI not XSS. Example: `http://www.vulnwebsite.com/view.php?var=/etc/passwd`

Comment: Yet, your example is vulnerable to XSS. E.g.: `file.php?var=data:,<svg onload=alert(1)>` XSS can be an implication of LFI, and in your case it is.

Comment: @Arminius Edited. This should be vulnerable only to LFI

Comment: @Abdelhafidh Belalia What you are describing **is not LFI**, you aren't calling include() this is just directory traversal and file disclosure - LFI is always code execution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability

Comment: @rook Right, Edited. Is the fix above enough, or it's exploitable?

Answer (score -1):

Edited : 
Yes , 
I really missed the point of the question sorry for that .Forward slash filtering will prevent LFI in Linux but it won't in Windows-based servers  . And LFI can lead to RCE I did that many times but it's another argument .

So you are safe if you are using Linux as you said but if someone used your script in Windows it easily bypassed by (..) backward slash .

The double encoding trick and hex won't work in this situation since you show the file after filtering .

That's all  what I know .

Comment: It is unclear to me how this answers the question

Comment: No, Simply No. LFI is not as RCE, and you can't exploit RCE using LFI else the header is set to serve a php file, and the it depends on the command that handle the user input; `file_get_contents` will not cause RCE. btw you have not answered my question yet.

Comment: @AbdelhafidhBelalia edited .